# Facebook Integration (iphone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I followed facebook developer's tutorial about facebook integration http://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

But the most of the codes are placed in the App delegate file.
After I sign in, I want to be redirected to my view controller wherein I will publish my post.
Should i transfer the codes from the appdelegate file to the view controller?
Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Add these 2 methods in your App delegates.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    return [ [[MyFacebookConnect sharedGameObject] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [[[MyFacebookConnect sharedGameObject] facebook] handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

Comment: ialready added this two methods on my app delegate. I want to instantiate a new view controller on the same story board. How could i instantiate a new view controller? Thanks for your time. Really appreciate it. I'm new in objective-c programming.